# Python/SciPy: How to get cubic spline equations from CubicSpline

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, spline

I am generating a graph of a cubic spline through a given set of data points:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

x = np.array([1, 2, 4, 5])  # sort data points by increasing x value
y = np.array([2, 1, 4, 3])
arr = np.arange(np.amin(x), np.amax(x), 0.01)
s = interpolate.CubicSpline(x, y)
plt.plot(x, y, 'bo', label='Data Point')
plt.plot(arr, s(arr), 'r-', label='Cubic Spline')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

How can I get the spline equations from `CubicSpline`? I need the equations in the form:
 [image]

I've attempted various methods to get the coefficients, but they all use data that was obtained using different data other than just the data points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline.html):

> **c** (ndarray, shape (4, n-1, ...)) Coefficients of the polynomials on each segment. The trailing dimensions match the dimensions of `y`,
>   excluding axis. For example, if `y` is 1-d, then `c[k, i]` is a
>   coefficient for `(x-x[i])**(3-k)` on the segment between `x[i]` and
>   `x[i+1]`.

So in your example, the coefficients for the first segment *[x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>]* would be in column 0:

- *y<sub>1</sub>* would be `s.c[3, 0]`
- *b<sub>1</sub>* would be `s.c[2, 0]`
- *c<sub>1</sub>* would be `s.c[1, 0]`
- *d<sub>1</sub>* would be `s.c[0, 0]`.

Then for the second segment *[x<sub>2</sub>, x<sub>3</sub>]* you would have `s.c[3, 1]`, `s.c[2, 1]`, `s.c[1, 1]` and `s.c[0, 1]` for *y<sub>2</sub>*, *b<sub>2</sub>*, *c<sub>2</sub>*, *d<sub>2</sub>*, and so on and so forth.

For example:

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 4, 5])  # sort data points by increasing x value
y = np.array([2, 1, 4, 3])
arr = np.arange(np.amin(x), np.amax(x), 0.01)
s = interpolate.CubicSpline(x, y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.hold(True)
ax.plot(x, y, 'bo', label='Data Point')
ax.plot(arr, s(arr), 'k-', label='Cubic Spline', lw=1)

for i in range(x.shape[0] - 1):
    segment_x = np.linspace(x[i], x[i + 1], 100)
    # A (4, 100) array, where the rows contain (x-x[i])**3, (x-x[i])**2 etc.
    exp_x = (segment_x - x[i])[None, :] ** np.arange(4)[::-1, None]
    # Sum over the rows of exp_x weighted by coefficients in the ith column of s.c
    segment_y = s.c[:, i].dot(exp_x)
    ax.plot(segment_x, segment_y, label='Segment {}'.format(i), ls='--', lw=3)

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Since the coefficients are accessible as an attribute (see @ali_m's answer) the approach shown here is unnecessarily indirect. I'm leaving it online should somebody using a more opaque library ever stumble over this question.

One way would be to evaluate at the node of interest:

```
coeffs = [s(2)] + [s.derivative(i)(2) / misc.factorial(i) for i in range(1,4)]
s(2.5)
# -> array(1.59375)
sum(coeffs[i]*(2.5-2)**i for i in range(4))
# -> 1.59375
```

Strictly speaking the higher derivatives don't exist at the nodes but scipy appears to return the right one-sided derivative, so it works even though it shouldn't.

Comment: I tried running this with a sample and the answer for the coefficients is not correct.

Comment: @jshapy8 would you be kind enough to share that sample? On the sample you posted it seems to work well enough.

Comment: On the sample I posted, the coefficients for S_1 should be as follows: 2, (-13/8), 0, (5/8) on [1,2]

Comment: @jshapy8 I get the same coefficients with my method and with @ali_m's method. If I evaluate your coefficients at `1.3`, say, I do not get the same as `s(1.3)`.

Comment: @ I don't know, different boundary conditions probably. You do realise that the coefficients depend on the boundary conditions? Why don't you try your coefficients and evaluate at a few points in `[1,2)` and then evaluate `s` at the same points?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! If i include `bc_type=((2, 0.0), (2, 0.0))`, which is for natural spline, I get the coefficients I expect.