# How to solve a cubic function without knowing the coefficients a b and c?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, cubic

Apology for this silly question. In the cubie function below (as from a school project), I am given the value for x and f(x) while coefficients a, b ,c and constant of d are unknown.

```
f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d
```

In such case, is there a way to find out a, b and c by using any python package? I found good amount of python tutorial for solving cubic function but they seem to mainly focus on solving x while a, b and c value are given.

Comment: Relevant here: [Mathologer: 500 years of NOT teaching the cubic formula](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-KXStupwsc) and [the cubic formula on Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html).

Comment: If you have 4 different `x` and `f(x)` pairs, you can solve the set of 4 linear equations, e.g. via sympy's `solve` or `interpolate` function.

Comment: Thanks @JohanC, these info are very valuable and helpful. Let me study about it and possibly come back to you with more questions, but this is certainly a great starting point for solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach via [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html), Python's symbolic math library.

As an example, we are trying to find the formula for the sum of the first `n` triangular numbers. The triangular numbers (formula `n*(n+1)/2`) are `0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, ....`.  The sums of the first `n` triangular numbers are thus `0, 1, 4, 10, 20, 35, 56, ...`.

```py
from sympy import Eq, solve
from sympy.abc import a,b,c,d, x

formula = a*x**3 + b*x**2 + c*x + d  # general cubic formula
xs = [0, 1, 2, 3]  # some x values
fxs = [0, 1, 4, 10]  # the corresponding function values

sol = solve([Eq(formula.subs(x, xi), fx) for xi, fx in zip(xs, fxs)])
print(sol)  # {a: 1/6, b: 1/2, c: 1/3, d: 0}
```

You can use more `x`, `fx` pairs to check that a cubic formula suffices (this won't work with float values, as sympy needs exact symbolic equations).

Also sympy's `interpolate` can be interesting.  This calculates a polynomial through some given points.  Such code could look like:

```py
from sympy import interpolate
from sympy.abc import x

xs = [0, 1, 2, 3]
fxs = [0, 1, 4, 10]
fx_dict = dict(zip(xs, fxs))
sol = interpolate(fx_dict, x)
print(sol)  # x**3/6 + x**2/2 + x/3
print(sol.factor())  # x*(x + 1)*(x + 2)/6
```

Comment: Thanks @JohanC a lot for this. what happens if I have float instead of integer for x values? Since I don't want to round up the float to integer, is there an alternative or work around solution for that?

Comment: Sympy also supports fractions.  E.g. via [nsimplify()](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html#nsimplify).  You *can* work directly with floats, but due to approximation errors, the result might look weird.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43458414/python-scipy-how-to-get-cubic-spline-equations-from-cubicspline for a numeric approach (instead of symbolic).

Comment: Another approach is numpy's [Polynomial.fit(xs, fxs, 3)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit.html) which tries to find the closest cubic to a list of value pairs (it would be exact with 4 or less pairs and approximating with more pairs).

Comment: Thanks JohanC, I just realized I have 4 more pairs of xs and fxs (turns out I have more than 100 paris), perhaps the above solution is not for situation like this?

Comment: Sympy is best for exact solutions with exact data. Numpy and scipy solutions can do best fits for many approximating data.  Everything depends on what you want to do with the result and why you think that a cubic would be a good representation for your data. The current answer is meant for how you formulated your original question.  Feel free to create a new question which better describes the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: thanks. By using your advice, I posted a new question here. Would be great if you can give me some advice.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72736909/python-curve-fit-with-multiple-independent-variables-in-order-to-get-the-value