# Python curve_fit with multiple independent variables (in order to get the value for some unknow parameters)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

Is there a way to use curve_fit to fit for a function with multiple independent variables like below?

I try to get the value for a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2, a3, b3, c3 and d while x1, x2, x3 and y1 (dependent variable) are all known. I want to optimize these values to minimize my error by using scipy.optimize. Be noted in real situation, for x1, x2, x3 and y1, I have more than hundred data points.

Or if there is a better way or more appropriate way to get the value for a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2, a3, b3, c3 and d?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x1 = [3,2,1]
x2 = [3,4,2]
x3 = [1,2,4]
y1 = [5,7,9]

def func(x1, x2, a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2, d):
    return (a1*x1**3+b1*x1**2+c1*x1) +(a2*x2**3+b2*x2**2+c2*x2)  + d

def func2(x1, x2, x3, a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2, a3, b3, c3, d):
    return (a1*x1**3+b1*x1**2+c1*x1) +(a2*x2**3+b2*x2**2+c2*x2) + (a3*x3**3+b3*x3**2+c3*x3) + d
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `x1` and `x2` in **one** object, see description of `xdata` in [docs for `curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html):

> The independent variable where the data is measured. Should usually be
> an M-length sequence or an **(k,M)-shaped array** for functions with k
> predictors, but can actually be any object.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# generate sample data for a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2, d = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
np.random.seed(0)
x1 = np.random.randint(0, 100, 100)
x2 = np.random.randint(0, 100, 100)
y1 = (1 * x1**3 + 2 * x1**2 + 3 * x1) + (4 * x2**3 + 5 * x2**2 + 6 * (x2+np.random.randint(-1, 1, 100))) + 7

def func(x, a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2, d):
    return (a1 * x[0]**3 + b1 * x[0]**2 + c1 * x[0]) + (a2 * x[1]**3 + b2 * x[1]**2 + c2 * x[1]) + d

popt, _ = curve_fit(func, np.stack([x1, x2]), y1)
```

Result:

```
array([1.00000978, 1.99945039, 2.97065876, 4.00001038, 4.99920966,
       5.97424668, 6.71464229])
```

Comment: Thanks @Stef for this. Do you mind to clarify in yi, what does the 6 * (x2+np.random.randint(-1, 1, 100) do? Also, how will this work if I have 9 coefficient and 3 independent variables (x1, x2 and x3)? I will modify the question slightly to seek the solution. Thanks again.

Comment: The `+np.random.randint(-1, 1, 100)` is just to add some randomness to the generated sample data. For 9 coefficients and 3 variables it's exactly the same procedure, you need to row-stack the 3 variables.

Comment: Thanks Stef. My understanding is it would be y1 = (1 * x1**3 + 2 * x1**2 + 3 * x1) + (4 * x2**3 + 5 * x2**2 + 6 * (x2+np.random.randint(-1, 1, 100)))  +  (7 * x2**3 + 8 * x2**2 + 9 * (x2+np.random.randint(-1, 1, 100))) + 10 follow by  popt, _ = curve_fit(func, np.stack([x1, x2, x3]), y1) ?

Comment: yes for the `curve_fit` call, the `y1 = ...` is just to generate sample data for the example, you don't need to do this as you have your own `y1` values (of course, for k coefficients to fit you need at least k y1 values)

Comment: I tried that and I got a warning message saying "Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated"

Comment: Maybe you need to provide a (better) initial guess for the coefficients. There's no rule of thumb how to get these guesses unless you have some information from the underlying process you want to model.

Comment: do you mind to help me out on getting the fun2 works? I am having another error saying index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3

Comment: This means that your first dimension of x has only size 3, i.e. indices 0, 1, and 2 are possible. You should check your formula.  Also I noticed that you used `^` in your example, the power operator in python is `**`, not `^`!

Comment: this is what i have for y1: y1 = (1 * x1**3 + 2 * x1**2 + 3 * x1) + (4 * x2**3 + 5 * x2**2 + 6 * x2 ) +  (7 * x3**3 + 8 * x3**2 + 9 *x3) + 10 and this is what I have for func2 return (a1 * x[0]**3 + b1 * x[0]**2 + c1 * x[0]) + (a2 * x[1]**3 + b2 * x[1]**2 + c2 * x[1]) + (a3 * x[3]**3 + b3 * x[3]**2 + c3 * x[3]) + d, then this is what I have for popt, _ = curve_fit(func2, np.stack([x1, x2, x3]), y1) I can't really see what the issue is here?

Comment: in the last part of the equation in func2, it must be x[2] instead of x[3] (indices run from 0 to 2)